# Changing angular host through @input

Tags: angular

I was wondering how to change the style of my component through the angular `@Input()` decorator.

Reason of it was because I couldn't neither

1. Change the css through `@ViewChild` because this wasn't initialized at the `ngOnInit()`
2. pass it through `[style]` for some reason I cannot explain

I'll already give my solution, but if somebody have a better one, I'm open :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do was.

1. pass the variable from the parent to the child

#### parent.component.html

```html
<child-component css="background-color: black;"></child-component>
```

2. Change the css with `@HostBinding`

#### child.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html'
})
export class ChildComponentComponent {
  @HostBinding('style')
  style: string

  @Input() set css(value: string) {
    this.style = value || ''
  }
}
```